# pushViewController that's not a root viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, pushviewcontroller

I have two View Controllers: LevelSelectViewController and GameViewController.

Neither are the root view controller for the app I am making (the root view controller is called MainViewController).

How can I use the navigation method pushViewController:animated: for this transition for LevelSelectViewController to GameViewController?

In my LevelSelectViewController, you click a button and the following action method performs:

```
    - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
        // the pushViewController:animated: method hopefully can be used
        // other code
    }
```

Comment: How did you show `LevelSelectViewController`?

Comment: presentViewController...that's how I've been navigating throughout all the buttons in my app.  If I establish the root view controller as the navigation controller from AppDelegate, will I be able to use the other sub-viewcontrollers as navigation controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use the navigation method `pushViewController:animated:` for this transition for LevelSelectViewController to GameViewController?

The term "root view controller" can be a little confusing because `UIWindow` has a `rootViewController` property, and `UINavigationController` has a `initWithRootViewController` parameter. If you're calling `-pushViewController:animated:`, you must have a navigation controller in your view controller graph since that method belongs to `UINavigationController`. If your `LevelSelectViewController` instance is part of a navigation stack, you can do this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    // create a game controller
    GameViewController *gameController = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    // push it
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:gameController animated:YES];

    // other code
}
```

A more typical thing to do these days, though, is to put all the view controllers in a storyboard and simply connect the button to a push transition.

Comment: I didn't know that if you set up your root view controller as a navigation controller in App Delegate, the other children of that view controller will be able to enjoy the same feature as well (without having to redefine other navigation controller instances).....thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboards just create a segue. If you're not passing any information you can push to it by control dragging from one view controller to another. It doesn't matter if it's the root view controller or not.

If you want to pass data create a segue on storyboards from the view controller, not the index path or button etc. and invoke the prepareForSegueMethod in the view controller with the exact same identifier as the segue on storyboards.